# Can you export an animated ocean modifier as a series of images/textures, and if so, how?

Tags: animation, texturing, ocean-simulation

Pretty much as the title says.

I've found many tutorials on animating a looping ocean modifier, but is it possible to take each frame of this animation and export it as a series of textures, which can later be applied to plane and used as a 2d looping animation.

Certain games wouldn't be able to handle the ocean modifier as an actual animation, but would definitely be able to handle a flat plane with an animated texture. My question is - how do I take the 3d animation and turn it into a series of frames/2d textures?

Comment: you'd have to render/bake a texture(s) for each frame. At a minimum you'd need color and displacement maps.

Comment: are you meaning something like rendering to a "video sequence" and use that as a texture? that could work, if it fits in your setup